# How to unroll the training loop so that Jax can train multiple steps in GPU/TPU

Tags: jax, flax

When using powerful hardware, especially TPU, it is often preferable to train multiple steps. For example, in TensorFlow, this is possible.

```
with strategy.scope():
  model = create_model()
  optimizer_inner = AdamW(weight_decay=1e-6)
  optimizer_middle = SWA(optimizer_inner)
  optimizer = Lookahead(optimizer_middle)
  training_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean('training_loss', dtype=tf.float32)
  training_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(
      'training_accuracy', dtype=tf.float32)

# Calculate per replica batch size, and distribute the `tf.data.Dataset`s
# on each TPU worker.
actual_batch_size = 128
gradient_accumulation_step = 1
batch_size = actual_batch_size * gradient_accumulation_step
steps_per_epoch = 60000 // batch_size
validation_steps = 10000 // batch_size

train_dataset = get_dataset(batch_size, is_training=True)
per_replica_batch_size = batch_size // strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

train_dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function(
    lambda _: get_dataset(per_replica_batch_size, is_training=True))

@tf.function(jit_compile=True)
def train_multiple_steps(iterator, steps):
  """The step function for one training step."""

  def step_fn(inputs):
    """The computation to run on each TPU device."""
    images, labels = inputs
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      logits = model(images, training=True)
      loss = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
          labels, logits, from_logits=True)
      loss = tf.nn.compute_average_loss(loss, global_batch_size=batch_size)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

    optimizer.apply_gradients(list(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables)))
    training_loss.update_state(loss * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
    training_accuracy.update_state(labels, logits)

  for _ in tf.range(steps):
    strategy.run(step_fn, args=(next(iterator),))

train_iterator = iter(train_dataset)
# Convert `steps_per_epoch` to `tf.Tensor` so the `tf.function` won't get
# retraced if the value changes.

for epoch in range(10):
  print('Epoch: {}/10'.format(epoch))


  train_multiple_steps(train_iterator, tf.convert_to_tensor(steps_per_epoch))
```

In Jax or Flax, however, I haven't seen a complete working example of doing so. I guess it would be something like

```
@jax.jit
def train_for_n_steps(train_state, batches):
    for batch in batches:
        train_state = train_step_fn(train_state, batch)
    return train_state
```

However, in my case when I am trying to test the complete example, I am not sure how one can create multiple batches. [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sdJbSi3s-D8T21UoPdtCkkAhN9xgC2dG#scrollTo=XlmvTDfxFDqL) is a working example using GPU without training multiple steps. The relevant code should probably be here:

```
for step,batch in enumerate(train_ds.as_numpy_iterator()):

  # Run optimization steps over training batches and compute batch metrics
  state = train_step(state, batch) # get updated train state (which contains the updated parameters)
  state = compute_metrics(state=state, batch=batch) # aggregate batch metrics

  if (step+1) % num_steps_per_epoch == 0: # one training epoch has passed
    for metric,value in state.metrics.compute().items(): # compute metrics
      metrics_history[f'train_{metric}'].append(value) # record metrics
    state = state.replace(metrics=state.metrics.empty()) # reset train_metrics for next training epoch

    # Compute metrics on the test set after each training epoch
    test_state = state
    for test_batch in test_ds.as_numpy_iterator():
      test_state = compute_metrics(state=test_state, batch=test_batch)

    for metric,value in test_state.metrics.compute().items():
      metrics_history[f'test_{metric}'].append(value)

    print(f"train epoch: {(step+1) // num_steps_per_epoch}, "
          f"loss: {metrics_history['train_loss'][-1]}, "
          f"accuracy: {metrics_history['train_accuracy'][-1] * 100}")
    print(f"test epoch: {(step+1) // num_steps_per_epoch}, "
          f"loss: {metrics_history['test_loss'][-1]}, "
          f"accuracy: {metrics_history['test_accuracy'][-1] * 100}")
```

My goal is to unroll 5 loops when training.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I think JIT-ing the loop like you've said would be the way to do it. It'll make compilation take way longer and I don't know if it'll actually improve performance.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what is the exact way of doing it. How did you make it runnable? I just encountered a syntax error....

Comment: What did the error say?

Comment: If you check the functions here, then there is no such thing as loop unrolling in the original jit code. https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.jit.html#jax.jit.

Comment: The JIT works by tracing the execution of a python function. Because your loop runs a static number of times, the loop will effectively be unrolled.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure what you mean by that. What I face is that I have a TPU which is very powerful and if I feed the loop only once, then its computational power is not fully realized. As is shown in the TensorFlow example, it is possible to send multiple batches to the TPU.

Comment: Okay I'll just make a full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `more_itertools.chunked` to get something like this:

```py
for step, five_batches in chunked(train_ds.as_numpy_iterator()):
    state = five_steps(state, five_batches):
```

Then do the unrolling

```py
@jax.jit
def five_steps(state, batches):
    for batch in batches:
        state = train_step(state, batch)
    return state
```

The reason this works is that `batches` has a length that isn't data dependent, so the loop will just get executed 5 times during tracing.

This will likely make jitting take much longer than you want, so the perferred but more difficult way is to pack the batches into `[N x batch_size x ...]` tensors, then use [scan](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.scan.html) to loop your update function over the inputs.

Comment: While you are writing, I have actually used this one. However, there is some weird behavior in the code. Most, importantly, it seems that the metrics are not computed. Here is the Colab notebook https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rwbfd/0a4111863f2d5ad1ddca654721ff8759/geek_bang_chapter_13_part2.ipynb

Comment: I think you should divide `num_steps_per_epoch` by 5 since each update of `step` is now 5 steps. You could also do `step += 5`, but then your `if (step+1) % num_steps_per_epoch == 0:` check might be skipped

Comment: Done. This is the complete notebook. https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rwbfd/cee859ae5ac6bd1cfa49fca250423f7f/geek_bang_chapter_13_part2.ipynb.